# run a wodpress shortcode in totally custom file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, shortcode

so I have a Wordpress page where I want to fetch the data... so I am using javascript ajax to get data from a PHP file... which is totally custom build... I want to run a shortcode of WordPress in this custom file and send the HTML of shortcode to the WordPress page...

here's the javascript

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        showjob();
    });
    function showjob() {    
    var intrest=document.getElementById("intrest").value; 
        jQuery.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'jobsloader.php',
            data: {
                intrest: intrest,
                type: 'need'
            },
            success: function(data) 
            {
                document.getElementById("addcontainer").innerHTML = data;
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

here's the custom file code:

```
 <?php
 if ($_GET)
 {
 ?>

 <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid">

 <?php

    $intrest=$_GET['intrest'];
    $search = "SELECT * FROM `$database`.`$job` where intrest='employee' && poj='$intrest'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $search);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
=======================================================================
<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3">
    <div class="vc_column-inner ">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="centered-box sc-image-centered-box">
                 <div class="sc-image sc-wrapbox sc-wrapbox-style-11 sc-wrapbox-position-centered" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;">
                    <div class="sc-wrapbox-inner"><img onclick="loaddetail(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)" class="sc-wrapbox-element img-responsive img-circle" src="<?php echo "../cloud/ads/".$row['addpic'].".png"; ?>" alt=""></div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                 <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                      <p style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></p>
                 </div>         
             </div>
             <div class="vc_btn3-container vc_btn3-center">
                 <button class="vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-modern vc_btn3-block vc_btn3-icon-left vc_btn3-color-grey"><i class="vc_btn3-icon fa fa-handshake-o"></i> Full Details</button>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 ======================================================================
```

So the whole above code is just the html part of the below shortcode... also this html doesnt work properly[css problems]... so i want to make the shortcode work here and then send the worked code to the wordpress page.... how to???

or if I can send the shortcode as a text and make it work in WordPress page... that will be ok too.  but how to???

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode("[sc_team style="horizontal" team="abc" columns="1"]"); ?>
 <?php
    }
 ?>
 </div>
 <?php  
 }
 else
 {
    echo "Please Try Again Later.";
 }
 ?>
```

sorry for bad explanation, for more details plz comment .... and dont downvote cause i didnt find any answer from other places... and i am stuck on it...

Comment: the custom file is present at the root folder... in case answer need it...

Comment: `the custom file is present at the root folder` make it a plugin instead. I guess you could include it from a plugin, but I wouldn't.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix i didnt get what you just said... can you please elaborate it??

Comment: The easiest thing is to make it a plugin, in the wp-content/plugins folder.  It takes very little work.

Comment: As others have mentioned, it could be a plugin.. or you could add this into your theme functions.php. People are suggesting using a plugin (or theme file) because then WP is loaded in that scope, where it's NOT loaded in other "custom" php files. It is definitely possible to handle this outside of wordpress, but it's messy. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files

Answer (score 0):

Make it a plugin, which is easy to do.

Create a folder named `myplugin` in `wp-content/plugins` in the folder put a file named `myplugin.php` (same as the folder).  In that file put this

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name:   MyPlugin
 * Version:       1.00.00
 * Plugin URI:
 * Description:   Some Description
 * Author:        Me
 * Author URI:    
 * License: Copyright (c) 2018 Me. All rights reserved.
 */

if(!function_exists('myshortcode')){
    function myshortcode($atts, $contents=''){
       $atts = shortcode_atts( [
         'post_id' => '',
       ]);
       ...
   }
}

add_shortcode( 'myshortcode', 'myshortcode');
```

Then go to the plugin page, and enable it.

Comment: well, i noob in wordpress... i still didnt get.... how will this benefit me... and how does it works??

Comment: It benefits you because instead of some messy "hack" it uses WordPress functionality.  So it executes when it's supposed to.  You need some way to tell wordpress what this short code means, and if you don't want it part of the theme code, then a plugin is your best bet.

Comment: as to how it works, WordPress has great documentation, for example https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin Which is way more information than you need, but there you go.